# Suffix to convert scientific notation to a type other than double

Tags: c++, literals, scientific-notation

I'm looking for a literal which would convert scientific notation to a type other than double. In my case, i need `uint64_t`. It should do something like this:

```
uint64_t x = 1e6_ui64;
```

But I'm not sure if there is something already present in C++ or one of its standard libs.

Where can I find literals for scientific notation? Do they exist in C++? Or should I implement them myself?

Comment: There is no such standard suffixes, because there is no much sense in these. You need to implement your own if you really need it.

Comment: Maybe a simple `static_cast` would do the job (assuming the value is representable as an `uint64_t`).

Comment: It's probably more readable to use digit separators: `1'000'000`.

Comment: @j6t `1e6` is just an example, I also need it for numbers as big as `1e15`